# How do I fix black lines in laptop LCD that are getting longer?

Tags: laptop, display

A few days ago black lines started to appear on my laptop LCD and, over time, they are getting bigger and longer.

[image]

I performed a quick search on the Internet and found out that they may be dead or stuck pixels. I am pretty sure they aren't cracks.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You should take a picture and add it to your question.

Comment: It may be an issue with the GPU too. Have you tried connecting an external display to see if the problem persists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dead pixels can not be easily fixed, it requires replacing the entire LCD screen. If the laptop is under warranty I suggest you contact the company for repair.

Stuck pixels can be triggered using software to get them working again, follow this guide: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/best-software-solutions-to-fix-a-stuck-pixel-on-your-lcd-monitor/

Comment: And if it is not covered by warranty, we can just have the LCD replaced, right?

Comment: The weird thing is, the lines seem to be moving. One time they are at a certain point then they are in some point close to the previous point.

Answer (score 0):

Many laptops use a graphics gpu from Intel.  I had this same problem with a brand new HP laptop running Windows 10.  Downloaded new driver for the gpu which was only six months newer than what came on the laptop originally.  Problem fixed!