# How to get rid of horizontal black lines in laptop LCD that are getting longer?

Tags: laptop, display

One day I turned on my laptop and found that there is black line on screen and this line was getting longer day by day, few days after I found  one more line. Why this is happening? I am sure that they are not cracks as I handle my laptop witg care.
For reference I am attaching a picture of my screen.
Lines are on bottom left corner and top right corner.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Have you powered down and completly restarted the laptop since this started?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix black lines in laptop LCD that are getting longer?](http://superuser.com/questions/700478/how-do-i-fix-black-lines-in-laptop-lcd-that-are-getting-longer)

Comment: @Tyson, yes I did but nothing happens.

Comment: That's an important fact that you should edit into your question body.  I asked because many users don't understand that power-down/reboot is very much different than close the lid and sleep.

Comment: @Tyson, okie, so any solution of this problem?

Comment: Personally, I don't have any beyond power down/reboot which can solve things like that sometimes.  @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 link is probably spot on, stuck or dead pixels.  If you're under warranty and the link in the linked answer doesn't help you then get the screen replaced.

Comment: From the picture this is most likely a hardware fault. looks like a soldering/contact problem. Look at the answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/700478/how-do-i-fix-black-lines-in-laptop-lcd-that-are-getting-longer